# Issue in downloading Talend Open Studio for ESB

Tags: talend

I am trying to download Talend open studio for ESB but when ever I download I am only getting Talend open studio for data Integration
But I need to get Talend open studio for ESB to do my work
Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

I think that now every download for ESB should be made from the sourceforge url :
https://sourceforge.net/projects/talendesb/